# Powershell script to find file age from an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm working on a powershell script to read file attributes filtered by CreationTime on multiple shares. The scripts works, sporadically. It works great when I use a single path but I get mixed results when I add the folders paths to an array. The most disturbing result is when it successfully find and reads all path and then includes everything under c:windows\system32. Same anomaly when shares are empty.

So what I want to accomplish is:

1. Read list of Shares
2. Read each share content filtered by 'CreationTime' and 'Archive' attributes.
3. Save results to a csv file.
4. If file not empty, write results to event log.

here is the code

```
$timer = (Get-Date -Format yyy-MM-dd-HHmm)
$Date=(Get-Date).AddHours(-3)
$FolderList = "C:\Software\Scripts\FolderList.txt"
$Folders = get-content $FolderList
$Filepath = "C:\Software\Scripts"
$filename = "$Filepath\" + $timer + "OldFiles.csv"

foreach ($Folder in $Folders)

{
Get-ChildItem $Folder | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $Date -and $_.Attributes -band [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Archive} | Select Attributes, CreationTime, Fullname | Export-Csv -Path $filename -NoTypeInformation
}

if ( (get-childitem $filename).length -eq 0 )

{

exit
}


  else{

#Write to OpsMgr Log
$Message = get-content $filename 
Write-EventLog -LogName "Operations Manager" -Source "Health Service Script" -EventID 402 -EntryType Information -Message "Old files found. $Message"

}
```

Comment: reading the system dir is caused by not having a valid path. that is the default location for some ways of starting PoSh. that indicates you have a problem in your `$FolderList` somewhere.

Comment: You do an `Export-Csv` to the same file name inside a foreach and thus overwrite the file on every iteration (`$folder`). But you only `Write-EventLog` once at the end thus having only the very last folder reported..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (untested) script might do what you want:

```
$Date = (Get-Date).AddHours(-3)

$FolderList = "C:\Software\Scripts\FolderList.txt"
$Folders    = Get-Content $FolderList
$Filepath   = "C:\Software\Scripts"

$timer    = (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm)
$filename = Join-Path $Filepath ("{0}_OldFiles.csv" -f $timer)

$Data = foreach ($Folder in $Folders){
    Get-ChildItem $Folder | 
      Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $Date -and 
                     $_.Attributes -band [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Archive} | 
        Select Attributes, CreationTime, Fullname 
}


if ($Data.Count){
    #Write to OpsMgr Log
    $Data | Export-Csv -Path $filename -NoTypeInformation
    $Message = $Data | ConvertTo-Csv
    Write-EventLog -LogName "Operations Manager" -Source "Health Service Script" `
                   -EventID 402 -EntryType Information `
                   -Message "Old files found. $Message"
}
```

Comment: works like a charm. many Thanks LotPings. `Join-Path` is a new one for me. reading the data before exporting it, simple but genius.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, If an answer solves your question you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or if you find it helpful [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the process to me. Still relatively new on the platform.